# Command pattern: shine some light

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm exploring the command pattern, and I'm trying to figure out the actual benefit of this pattern.
I have read the following article: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s08.html
And after staring at it long enough, I still fail to see the benefit of the implementation. Let me clarify what I don't get.

We have the following command object:

```
(function(){

  var CarManager = {

      // request information
      requestInfo: function( model, id ){
        return "The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar";
      },

      // purchase the car
      buyVehicle: function( model, id ){
        return "You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model;
      },

      // arrange a viewing
      arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
        return "You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ";
      }

    };

})();
```

Executed by:

```
CarManager.execute = function ( name ) {
    return CarManager[name] && CarManager[name].apply( CarManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
};
```

The article says that this is what we want to achieve:

```
CarManager.execute( "buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543" );
```

The explanation is what I have problems with:

> Taking a look at the above code, it would be trivial to invoke our
>   CarManager methods by directly accessing the object. We would all be
>   forgiven for thinking there is nothing wrong with this—technically,
>   it’s completely valid JavaScript. There are however scenarios in which
>   this may be disadvantageous.
>
> For example, imagine if the core API behind the CarManager changed.
>   This would require all objects directly accessing these methods within
>   our application to also be modified. This could be viewed as a layer
>   of coupling, which effectively goes against the OOP methodology of
>   loosely coupling objects as much as possible. Instead, we could solve
>   this problem by abstracting the API away further.

**What I fail to see** is how this solution is in any way beneficial over:

```
CarManager.buyVehicle("Ford Escort", "453543");
```

What do they mean "if the core API" changes? I assume that they are talking about the interface, ie. the methods of the command object and their implementations. But if either of them change, it doesn't seem to change anything in how the method is called (whether to use execute or not, both will not work if the method name changes).
Also, I don't see how the `execute` method decouples anything. Whether `execute` is called, or whether the method is executed directly, the calling object needs a reference to the command object anyway.
Also, in the article (see visual scheme), they mention a client, receiver, invoker and command object. In the example, I only see two objects (?).

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I can't possibly imagine most code being written the way the article mentions.  It would be hopelessly obtuse to read and understand and debug and there's just no reason to take a method name out of the hands of the parser and move it to runtime evaluation most of the time.  There might be a very few times when you actually have a method name in a string, but then you can just do `obj[methodName](arg1, arg2)`.  I see no reason to hide code behind a `.execute()` most of the time.

Comment: Also, Javascript is extremely flexible for API changes because arguments can be any type, any quantity and can be tested for type and value and quantity at runtime.  Growing and evolving an API over time can be done quite well without making the API consist of only one API call (`.execute()`) that takes an infinite variety of arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 I found that the code comes from this book: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript. So should I assume that the command pattern just abstracts the methods in an object, and that the way this api is called is rather trivial?

Comment: I just can't think of a situation where this design pattern would be a better way of coding except for situations where all you're allowed to pass is one string (e.g. a command line interpreter) and you need a function to sort out method from arguments that can then call the real methods.  But, that's a very specialized need that doesn't arise very often.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for explaining, makes sense. Between brackets, I got interested in checking out the pattern because Fluxible (Yahoo's Flux implementation for isomorphic JS) seems to make extensive use of it.

Comment: I think this might also make more sense in a strongly typed language like C++ where API and implementation are rigorously tied together.  In Javascript, you don't have to use this type of command pattern to achieve most of the objectives in the article because an object can easily serve as a proxy for real implementations, even without knowing what arguments are passed to given methods.  You can't do that in C++ (or other strongly typed languages) without some sort of special design pattern like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that explanation misses the point. The [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is used to reify method calls ("action") so that you can deal with them programmatically. For example, you could store the command names in an array and execute them right after each other, or in the underlying API (the `execute` function) you could record them and store them for a replay.

Of course, JS being already pretty dynamic, this doesn't really change much (you always can execute methods by name using bracket notation), but you'd have the method name available as a string in that `execute` function so you can do something with it - which you otherwise would need an ES6 proxy for.

If the API changes, the code that uses it needs to change as well of course. That `execute` method might even be counter-productive, by making it not immediately clear that the string argument is a method name that needs to change (refactoring tools won't like this), and might not even throw an exception when you invoke it with the wrong name.

I guess the point that the article is trying to make here is that a facade is easier to implement when you already have this command pattern in place. You can deal with method names and arguments programmatically.

Let's say the `buyVehicle` method is changed to a `buyCar` method. Where you previously would have provided backward-compatibility by

```
CarManager.buyVehicle = CarManager.buyCar;
```

you could with the command pattern just insert the lines

```
if (name == "buyVehicle")
    name = "buyCar";
```

in the `execute` method. Not much of an advantage, but it might be for more complicated cases.

Comment: Being able to do execute / replay a series of actions and being able to do more by having method names as strings actually makes the most sense to me as a benefit.

Answer (score 3):

With `.execute('methodName', ...)`, you can change the underlying method name without affecting its public interface.

```
CarManager.execute('buyVehicle', 'Ford Escort')
```

might actually call

```
this.purchase(car)
```

*under the hood.*

---

That said, I've never actually seen `execute` in the wild. You do, however, see this pattern in many jQuery plugins, as it allows the plugin to only take up one spot in the `fn` namespace but execute lots of commands. Ex `var date = $('#myEl').datepicker('getDate')`

Comment: Would `this.purchase(car)` in that case be called from within `buyVehicle`? In that case, I still don't see the difference... What benefit does it actually give if we pass the method name as a string vs when we call it directly?

Comment: `buyVehicle` exists only as a key; the `execute` method maps it to whatever internal function it should call, allowing the public API to remain constant regardless of the names of the internal methods.

Comment: Thanks, I see now: although the example didn't make it too obvious for me, I understand the reasoning behind having the key available as a string, rather than applying the method name directly.

Answer (score 1):

Some general ideas:

1) The command pattern allows you to define one "single point of entry" to a certain action.

2) It's a clean way to build user GUIs around: Gather all you need for a given command and execute it. Create your menu structure out of your command structure...

3) This action can be called from whereever you want. You are not bound to use an instance of a special class.

4) It is a very strict way to bind rights and to force any action to pass along your given route.

5) Additionally this decoupled approach allows you to define macros and some sort of "scripted process". Don't know if you ever did something with MsAccess. The macro coding there could be called "command patterned".